# php error with mail() need clarification

Tags: php, email

im new to php and i need a bit of clarification. ive searched google but tooo many results, none clearly identify whats wrong with mine. since i dont get any errors im not sure whats happening.

the error im getting is this:

```
Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

so longstory short, this is a small bit of my code:

```
while( $sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult) ) { 
    mail($to,$subject,$mssg,'from:xyz');
}

if(mail($to,$subject,$mssg,'from:xyz')) {
echo "An e-mail was sent to $to with the subject: $subject";
} else {
echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address $to is valid";
}
```

what im trying to do is, i have a small database with names etc, with this loop above, its suppose to say that while theres a name in $sn_rowSelect, to feed it the message, essentially emailing the whole lot of emails.

the error says "expects string, array given' im assuming means the name gotten from the DB is gotten as an assosiative array value, but, isnt that what its supposed to do?

thanks in advance.

EDIT***

```
$to = $sn_rowSelect;
$from = $_POST['sender'];
$mssg = $_POST['message'];
```

from and mssg, are filled out via a form on another page.

Comment: Where do you set the `$to` variable? Because it's not set at all in the code you've shown.

Comment: Hi Emil, sorry. i edited my post above but to nswer your question, $to =s to $sn_rowSelect.

Comment: $sn_rowSelect is an array (http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array). So you are trying to pass an array insead of a string (first argument of the mail function). What SQL-query are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the $to parameter *inside* the while loop, and you need to set it to a string. You will also need to move the `if` statement inside the while loop if you want it to make sense, and you can't call mail() twice since that will create redundant emails.

Here's a fixed code for you:

```
$from = $_POST['sender'];
$mssg = $_POST['message'];

while($sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult) ) {
    $to = sn_rowSelect['email']; //change 'email' to the name of column in db
    $mailstatus = mail($to, $subject, $mssg, 'from:xyz');

    if($mailstatus) {
        echo "An e-mail was sent to $to with the subject: $subject\n";
    }else{
        echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address $to is valid\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you're supposed to get the actual users name as a string, not an array.

Something like `$row['name']` - do a `var_dump` of your value to find out how the data is stored, or a `print_r`.

Comment: Hey prisoner, ok so i didnt know what var_dump was, googled it, tested with it and i got some results. thanks for that. now, as far as the actual dump, i get 7 results for the dump which is the 7 email addresses in my database. so im assuming its working since its passing all the addresses from the db to my app,  just still doesn't explain what it means by " mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" which im still getting

Comment: It's because you're passing an array to the `$to` parameter of `mail()`. You should be passing something like `$to['email_column_in_database']`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to input an `array` that contains multiple e-mails directly into `$to`.

You *can* input multiple e-mails into the `mail` function, but they have to be separated by comma's.

So change this:

```
mail($to,$subject,$mssg,'from:xyz');
```

to:

```
$to = implode(",",$to);
mail($to,$subject,$mssg,'from:xyz');
```

Also be careful, you are doing a check *after* you are sending the mail like this:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$mssg,'from:xyz')) {
```

This will actually send the e-mail **again**. If you want to check if your e-mail function is working, add the `if` statement to the original code.